# Rails-link delete isn't working property after customize confirmation delete dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to customize confirmation dialog.
Before I customize confirmation dialog, everything perfect. When I click on delete link

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icon_delete.png", :border => 0), user, method: :delete ,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure delete:' + user.email } %>
```

Browser shows default confirm popup and I press on OK->this link call destroy() in UserController.
Now, I implement customize confirm popup 
in user.js.coffee

```
$.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
$.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) # look bellow for implementations
false # always stops the action since code runs asynchronously

$.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
link.trigger('click.rails')


$.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
html = """
     <div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Ã—</a>
         <h3>Are you sure Mr. President?</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <p>#{message}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>
         <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary confirm">OK</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     """
$(html).modal()
$('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

This time,when I clicked on delete link -

1. The browser didn't show customize confirm popup dialog or default popup dialog
2. The link called `show()` in UserController instead of `destroy()`
   --> What's going on here, everything worked perfectly before I implemented customize confirm dialog. I didn't change anything in route.rb.

I use Ruby version
1.9.3 and Rails version 4.0.0.My asset/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the implementation described here : http://rors.org/demos/custom-confirm-in-rails

The code that you posted is not indented the same as the code shown in the original article.  In coffee script indentation is very important, so if your real code is not indented correctly you should try that.

For instance, the first function should look like this:

```
$.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
  return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
  $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) # look bellow for implementations
  false # always stops the action since code runs asynchronously
```

Comment: It didn't about indentation problems.My code in file the same as code in link that you posted above

Comment: I saw on the firebug console that when I clicked on delete link,before it redirected to show() on UserController,javascript error.But I couldn't catch it?. It happened very fast

Comment: You need to figure out how to grab that error.  It's almost certainly the culprit.

Comment: I found out, firebug console error: $(html).modal is not a function.That line $(html).modal()-->cause error

Comment: That means that either you haven't included the bootstrap JS, or it's not included before your own code.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 days looking for the solution.In file application.js,just add 
line:

```
//= require bootstrap-modal
```

in order bootstrap modal() working.Everything perfect now